# Get GRUB prompt after adding Ubuntu 18.04 to dual boot with Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi, windows-10

I installed a second SSD in my Dell laptop's optical drive bay. I want to install Ubuntu 18.04.4 to dual boot with Windows 10. I created a bootable USB with Rufus. I disabled Windows **fast startup** and **secure boot** in BIOS, set USB as first boot device, and checked UEFI mode (not legacy). Then, the installation starts normally.

I choose to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 (the first option... this option also creates an /dev/sda for NTFS and I don't know why...) and everything is fine until it says to restart the computer.

After restart, I see only the grub command line (as you can see in the picture below) and I don't know what to do.

If I use **ls**, I can see some partions but nothing else not even in partitons.

If I change boot priority, I can only boot Windows 10.

In BIOS, UEFI it says in windows SSD, in USB bootable (which was made with Rufus) and not in the SSD with Ubuntu.

[picture of grub command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ss93T.jpg)

How may I solve this so I can choose Ubuntu or Windows and successfully boot either?

- I used boot repair and even though it was successfully repaired, [you can see the report here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/kMMGkSvTv3/), I still have the same problem.
- I installed the ssd with Ubuntu in my desktop pc and it worked perfectly there... (I also have there, a separate ssd with windows 10 installed)

Comment: This post is mostly for graphic card driver but I don't think that is an issue. If you see in the picture, its not a black screen, its the grub command line.

Comment: Everything you did in the first paragraph except _set USB as first boot device_ was 100% correct. You should not need to make the USB the first boot device; since you did, make sure to avoid having a USB flash memory drive with an OS on it attached when you reboot, or change it back so your internal drive is the first boot device.

Comment: Yes I did that too. PS: thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is some kind of problem with grub, the bootloader. Try booting off the USB stick again and use boot-repair [as outlined](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_:_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu) here. That usually fixes most issues.

If that doesn't work, please post a link to the summary report boot-repair creates.

Good luck!

Comment: If it does not work, post the link to the Summary Report it creates.

Comment: Thanks oldfred, I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: thank you, it was successful but nothing changed. you can check here http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/kMMGkSvTv3/ . Also I made an experiment and installed the ssd in my desktop and it worked there...

Comment: Your Ubuntu install looks correct. But your Windows install in UEFI, is trying to boot grub which is not correct. You need to delete Windows boot 0000 and create new Windows UEFI boot entry. It looks like you did IV, but need to do the restore Windows part. https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win Do you have drives in AHCI mode? Have you updated UEFI and updated SSD firmware?